# I can't route any traffic no matter what is inbound or outbound on my GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I can't route any traffic no matter what is inbound or outbound on my GCE which was made by my custom-image, and it caused some google-guest-environment could not be started. By the way, I used the network connect test from one to the instance, and the result seems well(I think it because I set right firewall in my VPC), but I still cant't route any traffic in my VM.

---

**The serial-console log output.**
*ps.use `ifconfig` command, the `eth0` network card was not attached.*

```
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
```

**How I tested the network**
I used `ping`,`nmap`,etc to testing network in serial-console. `nmap` shows "Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn",`ping` command didn't work.

[image: network-connect-test Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my firewall rules were set all rights in my VPC. I have found the answer in this link https://www.cyberithub.com/failed-to-start-lsb-bring-up-down-networking/.

I just have ran the commands below and then recovered network.

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager 
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager 
# sudo systemctl status NetworkManager -l    # check the status and find no failed.
sudo service network restart
```